I installed new version ubuntu. Now my computer has slowed down. What to do?
Introduction
Recently I upgraded to the Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS. Since then my computer seems to have slowed down. Even when I type into the keyboard I notice it is slowed down. However, it might be a conincidence. Perhaps my computer was slowing down before I upgraded to Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS.  All I know is that I am getting frustrated and losing productivity. I looked at a few similar questoins and tried to make heads or tails of my situtation. I need some help.
The questions, answers, and comments in [1] are relevant to my problem. I typed top and see that gnome-shell is using 25-40% of my CPU. Firefox (when minimal tabs open) is eating 5-7%. Firefox when I have videopages (i.e., things like netflix) is eating 30% or more of the CPU. When I compile *.tex files with Texmaker 100% of my CPU is used.
The questions, answers, and comments in [2] relevant to my problem.
(A) I tried looking at my hard drive using sudo smartctl -t long /dev/nvme0n1. What I got was

Read Self-test Log failed: Invalid Field in Command (0x4002)

(B) I typed sudo fdisk -l. What I got  was:
Read Self-test Log failed: Invalid Field in Command (0x4002)

Disk /dev/loop0: 4 KiB, 4096 bytes, 8 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 55.66 MiB, 58363904 bytes, 113992 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 55.36 MiB, 58052608 bytes, 113384 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 63.97 MiB, 67080192 bytes, 131016 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 74.25 MiB, 77852672 bytes, 152056 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 63.7 MiB, 66789376 bytes, 130448 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop6: 73.88 MiB, 77463552 bytes, 151296 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop7: 273.61 MiB, 286900224 bytes, 560352 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 238.47 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Disk model: WDC PC SN730 SDBQNTY-256G-1001          
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 16A7BEFD-1231-4939-803B-7DB462F6426F

Device             Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1      2048  23437311  23435264  11.2G Linux swap
/dev/nvme0n1p2  23437312 218748927 195311616  93.1G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p3 218748928 220702719   1953792   954M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p4 220702720 500117503 279414784 133.2G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/loop8: 272.98 MiB, 286236672 bytes, 559056 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop9: 11.11 MiB, 11649024 bytes, 22752 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop10: 164.82 MiB, 172830720 bytes, 337560 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop11: 504.15 MiB, 528642048 bytes, 1032504 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop12: 505.09 MiB, 529625088 bytes, 1034424 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop13: 164.82 MiB, 172830720 bytes, 337560 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop14: 91.69 MiB, 96141312 bytes, 187776 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop15: 12.2 MiB, 12791808 bytes, 24984 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop16: 10.67 MiB, 11186176 bytes, 21848 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop17: 38.83 MiB, 40714240 bytes, 79520 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop18: 44.14 MiB, 46280704 bytes, 90392 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop19: 564 KiB, 577536 bytes, 1128 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop20: 321.08 MiB, 336678912 bytes, 657576 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop21: 568 KiB, 581632 bytes, 1136 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop22: 321.1 MiB, 336699392 bytes, 657616 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

(C) grep -i sda /var/log/syslog* . A small portion of what I got (so much came  out that I exceeded stackechange boy limit of 30000 characters) was:
 /var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-18T17:56:10.395808-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[1963]: Stopped target org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Housekeeping.target - GNOME maintenance of expirable data target.
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-18T17:56:10.396343-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[1963]: Stopped target org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Keyboard.target - GNOME keyboard configuration target.
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-18T17:56:10.396710-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[1963]: Stopped target org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.MediaKeys.target - GNOME keyboard shortcuts target.
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-18T17:56:10.397096-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[1963]: Stopped target org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.target - GNOME power management target.
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-18T17:56:10.397421-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[1963]: Stopped target org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.PrintNotifications.target - GNOME printer notifications target.
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-18T17:56:10.397686-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[1963]: Stopped target org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Rfkill.target - GNOME RFKill support target.
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-18T17:56:10.398376-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[1963]: Stopped target org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.ScreensaverProxy.target - GNOME FreeDesktop screensaver target.
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-18T17:56:10.401417-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[1963]: Stopped target org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Sharing.target - GNOME file sharing target.
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-18T17:56:10.401781-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[1963]: Stopped target org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Smartcard.target - GNOME smartcard target.
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-18T17:56:10.402106-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[1963]: Stopped target org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Sound.target - GNOME sound sample caching target.
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-18T17:56:10.402340-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[1963]: Stopped target org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Wacom.target - GNOME Wacom tablet support target.
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-18T17:56:10.402582-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[1963]: Stopped target org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.XSettings.target - GNOME XSettings target.
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-18T17:56:10.416611-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[1963]: Stopping org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Color.service - GNOME color management service...
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-18T17:56:10.417706-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[1963]: Stopping org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Keyboard.service - GNOME keyboard configuration service...
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-18T17:56:10.418245-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[1963]: Stopping org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.MediaKeys.service - GNOME keyboard shortcuts service...
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-18T17:56:10.420038-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[1963]: Stopping org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.service - GNOME power management service...
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-18T17:56:10.420530-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[1963]: Stopping org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Wacom.service - GNOME Wacom tablet support service...
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-18T17:56:10.426760-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[1963]: Stopped org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.XSettings.service - GNOME XSettings service.
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-18T17:56:10.427295-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[1963]: org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.XSettings.service: Consumed 7.619s CPU time.
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-18T18:14:10.965486-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2577]: Dependency failed for org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.XSettings.service - GNOME XSettings service.
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-18T18:14:10.965664-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2577]: org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.XSettings.service: Job org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.XSettings.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-18T18:14:10.966240-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2577]: Reached target org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.XSettings.target - GNOME XSettings target.
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-18T18:14:10.987233-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2577]: Starting org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.A11ySettings.service - GNOME accessibility service...
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-18T18:14:10.997128-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2577]: Starting org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Color.service - GNOME color management service...
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-18T18:14:11.009891-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2577]: Starting org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Datetime.service - GNOME date & time service...
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-18T18:14:11.018616-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2577]: Starting org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Housekeeping.service - GNOME maintenance of expirable data service...
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-18T18:14:11.022503-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2577]: Starting org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Keyboard.service - GNOME keyboard configuration service...
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-18T18:14:11.030533-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2577]: Starting org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.MediaKeys.service - GNOME keyboard shortcuts service...
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-18T18:14:11.045860-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2577]: Starting org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.service - GNOME power management service...
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-18T18:14:11.060985-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2577]: Starting org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.PrintNotifications.service - GNOME printer notifications service...
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-18T18:14:11.061815-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2577]: Starting org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Rfkill.service - GNOME RFKill support service...
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-18T18:14:11.067266-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2577]: Starting org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.ScreensaverProxy.service - GNOME FreeDesktop screensaver service...
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-18T18:14:11.078058-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2577]: Starting org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Sharing.service - GNOME file sharing service...
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-18T18:14:11.090008-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2577]: Starting org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Smartcard.service - GNOME smartcard service...
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-18T18:14:11.107623-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2577]: Starting org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Sound.service - GNOME sound sample caching service...
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-18T18:14:11.116895-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2577]: Starting org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Wacom.service - GNOME Wacom tablet support service...
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-18T18:14:11.120975-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2577]: Started org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.A11ySettings.service - GNOME accessibility service.
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-18T18:14:11.148467-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2577]: Reached target org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.A11ySettings.target - GNOME accessibility target.
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-18T18:14:11.438181-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2577]: Started org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Smartcard.service - GNOME smartcard service.
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-18T18:14:11.438654-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2577]: Started org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Datetime.service - GNOME date & time service.
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-18T18:14:11.439026-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2577]: Started org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Housekeeping.service - GNOME maintenance of expirable data service.
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-18T18:14:11.458726-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2577]: Started app-gnome-org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.DiskUtilityNotify-3119.scope - Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-18T18:14:11.462759-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2577]: Reached target org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Datetime.target - GNOME date & time target.
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-18T18:14:11.463094-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2577]: Reached target org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Housekeeping.target - GNOME maintenance of expirable data target.
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-18T18:14:11.463407-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2577]: Reached target org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Smartcard.target - GNOME smartcard target.
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-18T18:14:11.495528-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2577]: Started org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.ScreensaverProxy.service - GNOME FreeDesktop screensaver service.
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-18T18:14:11.496135-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2577]: Started org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Sharing.service - GNOME file sharing service.
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-18T18:14:11.496943-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2577]: Reached target org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.ScreensaverProxy.target - GNOME FreeDesktop screensaver target.
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-18T18:14:11.497248-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2577]: Reached target org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Sharing.target - GNOME file sharing target.
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-18T18:14:11.505891-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2577]: Started org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.PrintNotifications.service - GNOME printer notifications service.
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-18T18:14:11.506687-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2577]: Reached target org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.PrintNotifications.target - GNOME printer notifications target.
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-18T18:14:11.574474-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2577]: Started org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Sound.service - GNOME sound sample caching service.
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-18T18:14:11.574798-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2577]: Reached target org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Sound.target - GNOME sound sample caching target.
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-18T18:14:11.768442-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2577]: Started org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Rfkill.service - GNOME RFKill support service.
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-18T18:14:11.768683-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2577]: Reached target org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Rfkill.target - GNOME RFKill support target.
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-18T18:14:14.131565-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2577]: Started org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Color.service - GNOME color management service.
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-18T18:14:14.131939-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2577]: Reached target org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Color.target - GNOME color management target.
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-18T18:14:14.136367-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2577]: Started org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Keyboard.service - GNOME keyboard configuration service.
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-18T18:14:14.136959-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2577]: Reached target org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Keyboard.target - GNOME keyboard configuration target.
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-18T18:14:14.218591-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2577]: Started org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Wacom.service - GNOME Wacom tablet support service.
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-18T18:14:14.220002-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2577]: Reached target org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Wacom.target - GNOME Wacom tablet support target.
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-18T18:14:14.227331-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2577]: Started org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.MediaKeys.service - GNOME keyboard shortcuts service.
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-18T18:14:14.227659-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2577]: Reached target org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.MediaKeys.target - GNOME keyboard shortcuts target.
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-18T18:14:14.259896-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2577]: Started org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.service - GNOME power management service.
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-18T18:14:14.260214-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2577]: Reached target org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.target - GNOME power management target.
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-18T19:04:00.908487-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2577]: Starting org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.XSettings.service - GNOME XSettings service...
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-18T19:04:01.442827-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2577]: Started org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.XSettings.service - GNOME XSettings service.
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-19T20:01:06.803279-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2577]: org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Housekeeping.service: Consumed 4.074s CPU time.
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-19T20:01:06.844468-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2577]: org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Sharing.service: Consumed 5.002s CPU time.
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-19T20:02:01.994346-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2144]: Dependency failed for org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.XSettings.service - GNOME XSettings service.
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-19T20:02:01.994562-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2144]: org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.XSettings.service: Job org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.XSettings.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-19T20:02:01.995076-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2144]: Reached target org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.XSettings.target - GNOME XSettings target.
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-19T20:02:02.024604-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2144]: Starting org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.A11ySettings.service - GNOME accessibility service...
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-19T20:02:02.028910-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2144]: Starting org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Color.service - GNOME color management service...
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-19T20:02:02.039312-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2144]: Starting org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Datetime.service - GNOME date & time service...
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-19T20:02:02.044635-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2144]: Starting org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Housekeeping.service - GNOME maintenance of expirable data service...
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-19T20:02:02.068675-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2144]: Starting org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Keyboard.service - GNOME keyboard configuration service...
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-19T20:02:02.077337-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2144]: Starting org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.MediaKeys.service - GNOME keyboard shortcuts service...
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-19T20:02:02.082232-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2144]: Starting org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.service - GNOME power management service...
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-19T20:02:02.092620-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2144]: Starting org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.PrintNotifications.service - GNOME printer notifications service...
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-19T20:02:02.097371-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2144]: Starting org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Rfkill.service - GNOME RFKill support service...
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-19T20:02:02.104346-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2144]: Starting org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.ScreensaverProxy.service - GNOME FreeDesktop screensaver service...
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-19T20:02:02.111559-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2144]: Starting org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Sharing.service - GNOME file sharing service...
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-19T20:02:02.116673-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2144]: Starting org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Smartcard.service - GNOME smartcard service...
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-19T20:02:02.124778-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2144]: Starting org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Sound.service - GNOME sound sample caching service...
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-19T20:02:02.129163-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2144]: Starting org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Wacom.service - GNOME Wacom tablet support service...
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-19T20:02:02.479008-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2144]: Started org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.A11ySettings.service - GNOME accessibility service.
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-19T20:02:02.481788-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2144]: Started org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Datetime.service - GNOME date & time service.
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-19T20:02:02.486048-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2144]: Started org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.ScreensaverProxy.service - GNOME FreeDesktop screensaver service.
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-19T20:02:02.486302-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2144]: Started org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Rfkill.service - GNOME RFKill support service.
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-19T20:02:02.486749-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2144]: Started org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Housekeeping.service - GNOME maintenance of expirable data service.
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-19T20:02:02.487078-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2144]: Started org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Sharing.service - GNOME file sharing service.
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-19T20:02:02.513906-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2144]: Started app-gnome-org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.DiskUtilityNotify-2643.scope - Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-19T20:02:02.517976-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2144]: Reached target org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.A11ySettings.target - GNOME accessibility target.
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-19T20:02:02.518226-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2144]: Reached target org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Datetime.target - GNOME date & time target.
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-19T20:02:02.518419-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2144]: Reached target org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Housekeeping.target - GNOME maintenance of expirable data target.
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-19T20:02:02.518627-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2144]: Reached target org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Rfkill.target - GNOME RFKill support target.
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-19T20:02:02.518808-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2144]: Reached target org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.ScreensaverProxy.target - GNOME FreeDesktop screensaver target.
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-19T20:02:02.518986-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2144]: Reached target org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Sharing.target - GNOME file sharing target.
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-19T20:02:02.521626-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2144]: Started org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.PrintNotifications.service - GNOME printer notifications service.
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-19T20:02:02.527154-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2144]: Reached target org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.PrintNotifications.target - GNOME printer notifications target.
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-19T20:02:02.559331-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2144]: Started org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Smartcard.service - GNOME smartcard service.
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-19T20:02:02.560891-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2144]: Reached target org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Smartcard.target - GNOME smartcard target.
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-19T20:02:02.646553-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2144]: Started org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Sound.service - GNOME sound sample caching service.
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-19T20:02:02.647863-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2144]: Reached target org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Sound.target - GNOME sound sample caching target.
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-19T20:02:04.575039-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2144]: Started org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Keyboard.service - GNOME keyboard configuration service.
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-19T20:02:04.575563-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2144]: Reached target org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Keyboard.target - GNOME keyboard configuration target.
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-19T20:02:05.036616-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2144]: Started org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Color.service - GNOME color management service.
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-19T20:02:05.040604-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2144]: Reached target org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Color.target - GNOME color management target.
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-19T20:02:05.132436-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2144]: Started org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Wacom.service - GNOME Wacom tablet support service.
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-19T20:02:05.132724-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2144]: Reached target org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Wacom.target - GNOME Wacom tablet support target.
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-19T20:02:05.139632-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2144]: Started org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.MediaKeys.service - GNOME keyboard shortcuts service.
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-19T20:02:05.140840-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2144]: Reached target org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.MediaKeys.target - GNOME keyboard shortcuts target.
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-19T20:02:05.168678-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2144]: Started org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.service - GNOME power management service.
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-19T20:02:05.168948-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 systemd[2144]: Reached target org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.target - GNOME power management target.
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-19T20:02:05.600256-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 gsd-print-notif[1778]: Error releasing name org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.PrintNotifications: The connection is closed
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-19T20:02:05.602027-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 gsd-smartcard[1787]: Error releasing name org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Smartcard: The connection is closed
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-19T20:02:05.607990-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 gsd-housekeepin[1845]: Error releasing name org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Housekeeping: The connection is closed
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-19T20:02:05.609471-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 gsd-datetime[1798]: Error releasing name org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Datetime: The connection is closed
/var/log/syslog.1:2024-11-19T20:02:05.610424-05:00 michaeo-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5 gsd-sound[1823]: Error releasing name org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Sound: The connection is closed
grep: /var/log/syslog.2.gz: binary file matches
grep: /var/log/syslog.3.gz: binary file matches
grep: /var/log/syslog.4.gz: binary file matches

Questions
What should I do to ameliorate my situation?
References
[1] My computer runs slower now on Ubuntu
[2] Computer has slowed down A LOT!

Tip: Switch from Gnome to XFCE as your graphical environment. Remove Snap packages and install applications from .deb or .tar.gz packages (Firefox, thunderbird).

Link mentions 20.04, but I have done same for 22.04  & 24.04. I also prefer Kubuntu which is a bit lighter weight flavor.

@kyodake, is it very common to remove Gnome and replace with XCFE? Gow does one do that. Also, is it common to remove Snap packages?

@MichaelLevy removing snaps can be problematic as some snaps are required now for certain applications.  Especially if you use plain Ubuntu.  It may be easier if you're still early in your setup to just download the Xubuntu ISO and install fresh from the ISO rather than try and remove and install XFCE independently in the already done install

@Thomas Ward, Can you tell me how come I have so many loops? What are they? Can they be deleted?

Lastly, if i go with Xubuntu or if I go with  Kubuntu, will I lose all my data, or is it seamless the way that an upgrade to a new Ubuntu is?

@MichaelLevy the 'loops' are all the snaps and such that're mounted.  They don't actually exist as things you can just "delete".  And yes, you will llose all your data unless you back it up, you didn't say whether this was a brand new install or one you've had for a while.

I just upgrade from a previous LTS to the newest Ubuntu LTS. I like the idea of a new install to a lighter Ubuntu. I will have to pick the most suitable flavor for me. Thanks

What is your hardware if it's not a secret?

@MichaelLevy neofetch

ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Gen-5
--------------------------------------
OS: Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS x86_64
Host: 20UBCTOXUS ThinkPad X1 Yoga Gen 5
Kernel: 6.8.0-49-generic
Uptime: 37 mins
Packages: 2181 (dpkg), 14 (snap)
.   Shell: bash 5.2.21
Resolution: 1920x1080
DE: GNOME 46.0
WM: Mutter
WM Theme: Adwaita
Theme: Yaru [GTK2/3]
Icons: Yaru [GTK2/3]
Terminal: gnome-terminal
CPU: Intel i5-10210U (8) @ 4.200GHz
GPU: Intel CometLake-U GT2 [UHD Graphics]
Memory: 3618MiB / 7696MiB

I am having other problems since upgradeing.....  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1533563/vlc-is-not-opening-up

I have Core-i7 with 8Gb - Ubuntu 24.04 and Ubuntu 22.04 have the same speed. It is not surprise because kernel 6.8 on both systems. I fixed some Gnome issues upgrading to Gnome 46.

@Mahler, so this is something that I have to do on my own? My information says Gnome 46. Is this not one and the same?

@MichaelLevy Gnome is the part of Ubuntu. I had done 'do-release-upgrade' in the 22.04 terminal, and system upgraded to 24.04.
