VLC is not opening up
I recently upgraded to the lastest Ubuntu LTS. Upon doing so, it appears that VLC is not opening. This might be related to the overall slowness of my computer since I upgrade my LTS. As suggested in [1], I typed VLC in my terminal. Here is what comes up:
VLC media player 3.0.20 Vetinari (revision 3.0.20-1-g2617de71b6)
[00006100a9295a00] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway.
Qt: Session management error: Could not open network socket
Fontconfig warning: FcPattern object weight does not accept value [0 205)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

I have already uninstalled VLC and then re-installed VLC.
What else might I do?
[1] VLC media player is not opening

The solution is to replace the snap vlc with apt vlc, as mentioned in the post in my previous comment
